# Google sheets: how to return a value of array with double conditional?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have created a PM schedule (dates and type of service, 1st tab) and I want to know what formula delivers/displays the summary of units that require service (2nd tab). The typed date sets an entire week that should match with the second row of 1st tab, then search down all services  along the column and if it encounters a label (type of service) find the freight truck for service. I have tried with:

1. =VLOOKUP(E1,'Schedule 2022'!A2:GC,1,false)
2. =index('Schedule 2022'!D2:GC,match(A4,'Schedule 2022'!D2:GC2))
3. combinations with filter and importrange
   [File of preventive schedule for freigh trucks](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/102vhOVmc30rBSCohxAWdr-qENs0nne3EUx3r0jRiYt0/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance for your valuable support.

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand what you want to achieve, even with the example file. Would you be able to provide an example of the result that you're looking to obtain?

Comment: No because it was an original idea: a kind of query that delivers only the columns that matches with a written date (a week), then, by day, pull only the cells with a value different of 0 (the type of service) and finally apply a sort of reverse vlookup to know what freight truck needs service. In resume: the tab "Schedule 2022" displays only services (1-M, 1-S, 6-M etc) when an interval of time (any-day + 7 days) is typed on cell A6 of filter tab.